# Execute script parallel

Tags: bash

I have script which will execute as a argument from Central server like below-

```
`SCRIPT.sh host1`
```

Like above I have to execute on many hosts. so per host it will take 1min to execute.

```
SCRIPT.sh host1 
SCRIPT.sh host2 
SCRIPT.sh host3
......
.........
```

So far I am trying below simple for loop which take too much time.

```
for i in `cat host_list`;do echo $i;SCRIPT.sh $i;done
```

Any possibility to execute above for loop in parallel, I mean 50/100 hosts at a time.? 
Any suggestions please.

Comment: Use GNU `parallel`.

Comment: Replace `$i;done` with `$i & done`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "&" to run parallel batch commands with different shell.

```
for i in `cat host_list`;do echo $i;SCRIPT.sh $i & done
```

Also if there is lot of shell scripts you can put "wait" between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
parallel -j50 SCRIPT.sh :::: host_list
```

If `SCRIPT.sh` contains `ssh $1 "cmd; cmd; cmd"` then you can do this instead:

```
parallel -j50 --slf host_list --nonall 'cmd; cmd; cmd'
```